# Get sub webs from current web in SharePoint with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

I'm writing out every sub web in a custom navigation:

```
navigation = function (clientContext, web) {
    this.webCollection = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);

    clientContext.load(web);
    clientContext.load(this.webCollection, 'Include(Title, Url)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(navigationSuccess), Function.createDelegate(navigationFailed));
},

navigationSuccess = function () {
  var webEnumerator = this.webCollection.getEnumerator();
    while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
        // Writing out title/url for sub web.
    }
},
```

In navigationSuccess I want to check if this sub web contains any sub webs. Is this possible? I've tried web.get_webs() after get_current() but this I need to load first right (In a new function similar to "navigation")?

Feels like a big process for just check/count if current sub webs is containing any sub webs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve the number of sub sites using SharePoint JSOM:

```
function getWebsCount(parentWeb,success,error) 
{
    var ctx = parentWeb.get_context();
    var webs = parentWeb.get_webs(); //parentWeb.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
    ctx.load(webs);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
           success(webs.get_count());
        },
        error);
}
```

Usage

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
getWebsCount(web,function(count){
    console.log(String.format('Sub sites count: {0}',count));
},
function(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```